# Running OpenWRT with OpenVPN installed. Trying to configure to allow VPN connection through Windows 10 default VPN service

Tags: windows-10, router, vpn, openvpn, openwrt

I've imaged OpenWRT on my home router and I've run into trouble trying to connect through the VPN service on Windows 10 from my work machine through this.

I've installed `luci-app-openvpn`, `openvpn-easy-rsa`, and `openvpn-openssl` on my router but I'm unsure how to properly configure it to allow tunneling from my work client.

I'm not trying to set up a router rule for connection as my apartment is shared by other people who also connect to my router.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Installing OpenVPN on OpenWRT is well-documented. However, if you would like to avoid making your VPN available to other people, perhaps you should install OpenVPN on your computer instead.

Comment: Would this be viable on Windows 10 and through using simple authentication of password/username rather than config files? My priority is to both not allow the VPN through the router itself for all connections as well as compatibility with Windows 10.

Comment: Could you first better define the architecture you are trying to build: Where is the VPN, the clients and their connections and what is the role of the router here.

Comment: The VPN is one established by my work. The normal route to connect is through the Windows 10 VPN service that requires a server address, username, and password; This is on my work computer. My router is my personal router in my work from home setup that I have imaged with OpenWRT. The disconnect is that I am able to connect VPN services with Windows 10 through a connection with my modem directly, but not when connecting in through my OpenWRT router. Whatever's stopping my work laptop from connection through the Windows 10 VPN utility is the problem.

Comment: How have you configured it? Compare with [article1](https://www.ovpn.com/en/guides/openwrt) and [article2](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/client-luci).